# Printing a changed value into console log

Tags: javascript, html

I have an object called Susan that looks like this:

```
var Susan = {
age: 30,
lastName: "Dumb"
};
```

in my html file I have a text input and a submit button. Every time a button is pressed it calls a function that should change the Susan.age to whatever the user has written.

```
<input type = "text" id = "Up">
<button id = "btn1" onclick="SubmitFunc()">Submit</button>
```

The function itself looks like this:

```
function SubmitFunc()
{
Susan.age = document.getElementById("Up").value;
}
```

That part works fine but what I want to do is print that new value to Console but it doesn't work like I want it to. When I add:

```
Console.log(Susan.age);
```

to SubmitFunc function it only prints out the value at the moment when I click the button and then it disappears. When I just add it after the function it always outputs the default value of 30. I also tried to add onload function to body element but it also didn't work. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: *then it disappears* whant you mean by that ?

Comment: Where are you adding the console log? Within the `SubmitFunc()` function?>

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown it literally appears for split of a second and the just disappears.

Comment: @SinanGuclu yes the firsts time i tried by adding it to the SubmitFunc().

Comment: You mean, the console is cleared ? its wierd..

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown It is not cleared old stuff stays in there. My guess is cause the function only does it's stuff when the button is pressed but at first I expected that once Console log is made it will stay there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oki few updates:

- Add `this` (current object reference) to your onclick function call.
- You need to get the value from textbox, current you took from btn
- In `console.log`, c is in small ;)

```js
var Susan = {
age: 30,
lastName: "Dumb"
};

function SubmitFunc()
{
Susan.age = document.getElementById("Up").value;
console.log(Susan.age);
}
```

```html
<input type = "text" id = "Up">
<button id = "btn1" onclick="SubmitFunc(this)">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Id from a button was a copy-paste mistake it stands correctly in my original code.

Comment: I mean yes and no lol. I understand why it should work and in here when I press Run code snippet it does indeed work but for some reason it won't work in my browser. I will figure it out thank you for your answer.

Comment: Might be a caching issue. Hard refresh :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the element id in your function from "btn1" to "Up":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <script>
      var Susan = {
        age: 30,
        lastName: 'dumb'
      };

      function SubmitFunc(){
        Susan.age = document.getElementById('Up').value;
        console.log(Susan.age);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type='text' id='Up'/>
    <button id= 'btn1' onclick='SubmitFunc()'>Submit</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also consider using

```
<input type='button' value='Submit'/>
```

instead of the button tag (not necessary just a style recommendation).

Answer (score -1):

Modify like this: 
The reason is that your first console.log was due to old age that was not `reset` due to button click.
Also you need to read the value from the input field.

Lastly, in your code console.log had capital `C`.

```
var Susan = {
        age: 30,
        lastName: "Dumb"
    };
    function SubmitFunc() {
        Susan.age = document.getElementById("Up").value;
        console.log(Susan.age);
    }
```

Comment: This does not add any value to my answer. I have posted it before you. So if you have any updates please post else please remove. its just copy to what I gave

Comment: @Tushar Please look at the timing. I was just slow in typing. I didn't copy from your solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack OverFlow. The community persists on quality answers and improvements. If you post the same answer that is already there, what value do you add ?

Comment: @Tushar Did you look at my first line that says `The reason is that your first console.log was due to old age that was not reset due to button click.`  That line explains why he should not be confused with old value 30. Did you mention that?

Comment: @Tushar OP is asking `That part works fine but what I want to do is print that new value to Console but it doesn't work like I want it to. When I add console.log(Susan.age).`

Comment: lol reset, if you add it after function, it will just log the initial value. Where does button click come to picture here? And where the reset took place? It was never updated

Comment: @Tushar The reset is happening in the code that I proposed. So, if he doesn't put console.log there, he would see the old value.